# Count all cell values accross multiple columns that match a certain pattern in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, formula

I have an worked hours registration form where I also register my vacation hours and extra work hours.

When I work a number of hours on a day I just enter the hours worked, but when I'm using vacation hours I enter for example `v9` in the cell. `v` tells me it's vacation hours, but I can also register `p9` or `o9`. The number 9 may vary, but usually I take a whole day off, so 9 is okay.

I'd like to search the matrix and get a sum of all cells that start with `v`, `p` or `o` and sum up the number after the first character.

So I'd like to have calculate cell `K4` 9 because january 7 is registered as `v9`.

Can this be done?

See the attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you would need to use the vlookup function, I your case it probably will be =VERT.ZOEKEN( (more info https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)